# How to erase 1 line off a label text

Tags: text, label, line, erase

I'm writing a program where I add a line to a label by using += and using environment.newline to write down to the next line. What I need to know is if there is a way to take off the last line that was put up. I'm trying to tally up a qty and rewrite the line to adjust the qty.

Comment: Judging that he's saying environment.newline, it's probably c#

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, here are some ideas for you.

- Just rewrite the entire text with the new quantity instead of trying to go back and modify the old one.  Use separate variables to store the first part of the text and the quantity.
- You can use two labels.  One under another and just change the second label to update the quantity.